# Error when converting from Knit to pdf in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

**Code**

````
```{r, eval=TRUE}
library(caret)

plot(iris$Sepal.Length)
```
````

**Error reported**

> *pandoc.exe: pdflatex not found. pdflatex is needed for pdf output. Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 41 In addition:
>   Warning message: running command '"C:/Program
>   Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS t4.utf8.md --to
>   latex --from
>   markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash
>   --output t4.pdf --template "C:\Users\15235330\Documents\R\R-3.3.0\library\rmarkdown\rmd\latex\default-1.15.2.tex"
>   --highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex --variable graphics=yes --variable "geometry:margin=1in"' had status 41 
>   Execution halted No TeX installation detected (TeX is required to
>   create PDF output). You should install a recommended TeX distribution
>   for your platform:   Windows: MiKTeX (Complete) -
>   http://miktex.org/2.9/setup   (NOTE: Be sure to download the Complete
>   rather than Basic installation)   Mac OS X: TexLive 2013 (Full) -
>   http://tug.org/mactex/   (NOTE: Download with Safari rather than
>   Chrome _strongly_ recommended)   Linux: Use system package manager*

Comment: The error message is pretty clear about what is going wrong and how you can fix it. Have you installed MiKTeX as the message suggests?

Comment: I have installed MikeTex and pandoc already, but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

After getting a new computer, I found this post I wrote a year ago, and the technique I documented below still worked. However my original instructions were not clear, and I have updated to hopefully help others having the same challenge. Of course, YMMV.

I spent hours trying to resolve this. I installed Miktex, but was unable to get the packages directly from the package manager due to sitting behind a firewall at work.  I finally was able to resolve this using the following steps:

1. Install [Miktex](https://miktex.org/2.9/setup)

   - I used the basic installer
2. Create a folder to install Miktex packages, e.g. "C:\miktex_pkgs"
3. Go to the **[CTAN package archive](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages?lang=en)** and download the following .tar.lzma files:

   - fancyvrb
   - framed
   - microtype
   - miktex-zzdb1-2.9
   - miktex-zzdb2-2.9
   - mptopdf
   - titling
   - upquote
   - url
4. After downloading the above files, move the above .tar.lzma files to the folder you created, e.g. "C:\miktex_pkgs"
5. Open the MikTex Console Application downloaded in Step 1

   - Select "Packages"
   - Click "Install From" drop down
   - Click "change"
   - Select "Local package repository (file system)"
   - Click "Next",
   - Choose the folder you downloaded the .tar.lzma files to in Step 3
   - Click "Finish"
   - Click the "Update DB" logo next to the + - tool icons
   - Give a little bit of time to update.
6. The packages should now show in the package list in the Miktex Console
7. Close R studio out and re open.

Now you should be able to knit as PDF.